# how to read contents of file, write to outputstream and the re-read and Store in a string variable in memory in java

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, java-io

I need to read contents of a file, write them to an outputstream using an API Writer (PEMWriter - which converts the format of the contents to required format) and then re-read the newly formatted content from this outputstream and store in a String variable.

Anyone know how to do this?

in the words of code:

```
PEMWriter writer = null;
Writer out = null;
Reader in = null;
String priv = null;
KeyStore ks = null;

    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
         ks.load(new FileInputStream(MyConfig.KEYTOOL_FILE),
                 MyConfig.PASSWORD.toCharArray());
         KeyPair keyPair = getPrivateKey(ks, "myKey",
                 MyConfig.PASSWORD.toCharArray());
         PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

out = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(new org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream()));
writer = new PEMWriter(out);
 writer.writeObject(privateKey);
in = new  BufferedReader (new org.apache.commons.io.input.NullReader( new Long(5000).longValue()));

IOUtils.copy(in, out);

 priv = IOUtils.toString(in);
```

the above code should work as it has a Writer (out) which gets populated with contents of PEMWriter using bouncy castle api.  the problem occurs when trying to re -read the contents of out using Reader (in) and storing them to String (priv).  i get an IO Exception stating Read after end of file.  this occurs on line `IOUtils.copy(in, out);`.
i'd appreciate some help on this problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: If you get an exception, never forget to also post the stacktrace.

Comment: `new Long(5000).longValue()`? Why not just `5000L`? Masochism? :-) Also, I don't see how the code relates to the question? You don't have any file involved, and you read from a NullReader.

Comment: @JBNizet - i have edited original question to include previously omitted code - originally omitted to avoid unnecessarily cluttering of the question.

Comment: I don't see how it changes anything. You're still reading from a NullReader.

Comment: @JBNizet ks.load does 1st reading. i get the privateKey using the getPrivateKey.  now i write this to out using PEMWriter.  now i need a second read of the out so that i can save it to my String priv.  is my logic wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can't read a stream or reader twice. Once it's read to the end it's at the end (Done in `IOUtils.copy(in, out)`). Then you try to read it again (`IOUtils.toString(in)`).

To write both file and string in one step you could use a TeeWriter (like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/io-tools/source/browse/trunk/easystream/src/main/java/com/gc/iotools/stream/writer/TeeWriter.java?r=434)) and a StringWriter

Or copy the input to a String and write the string to out:

```
 priv = IOUtils.toString(in);
 out.wite(priv);
```

Comment: thanks, and i get this point. but what i dont get is that the initial write to out as below using writeObject() is where out now for 1st time has required contents so it should atleast allow me to read once using IOUtils.copy(). it doesnt throws Exception.  `out = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(new org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream()));
writer = new PEMWriter(out);
writer.writeObject(privateKey);
in = new  BufferedReader (new org.apache.commons.io.input.NullReader( new Long(5000).longValue()));
IOUtils.copy(in, out);`

Answer (score -1):

i believe the answer to my solution is to use pipes - a writer and reader pipe to connect the two together. so that i can read my out stream in a reader. i will only know after i try it out, but on research that seems the most correct ans to my problem 
similar to

```
 PipedWriter pwriter = new PipedWriter();
    PipedReader preader = new PipedReader(pwriter);
```